# Nuxt generate img with final random hash

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

I have two problems running

```
npm run generate
```

**First problem: [SOLVED]**

I have two duplicated img folders in the dist folder:

One is in:

```
 dist/img
```

and the other one is in

```
dist/_nuxt/img
```

in the dist/img folder the subfolder are maintained, in the dist/_nuxt/img not.

All the site img src are pointing to dist/_nuxt/img but I would like to use the dist/img/../ folder.

**[SOLUTION]** REMOVE @/asset from src <img src="@/static/img/ => <img src="/img/

**Second Problem:** *(not solved yet)*

Maybe can be solved, solving the first problem, all images are renamed with a final hash, and I don't like it, ex:

```
imganame.2354ur2bur2.jpg
```

How can I solve this problems?

Comment: Why do you care about the image name after the build?

Comment: Mmh, I don't know, all the IMG names are SEO oriented, I don't know the impact of the final hash sincerely

Comment: There is no impact on the filename, more of the `alt` attribute or any a11y properties. Otherwise, everybody would have been already screwed up.

Comment: Yes, but now I need to check, I'm afraid that every time I generate hash change..and this can cause 404

Comment: You don't really need to bother about this. The hash is here for caching-purposes essentially, to invalidate and ask for a refetch of the asset. Webpack is doing the rest.

Comment: Hi, did my post answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's quickly summarize your problem: when you reference an image like this:

```html
<img src="~/assets/your_image.png" />
```

it will be translated into

```html
<img src="/_nuxt/img/your_image.0c61159.png" />
```

after the build process with `nuxt generate`.

This is the default behaviour of [Webpack Assets](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/assets#webpack-assets). It resolves the reference, rename the file with version hashes for better caching, and copy & paste the file to the designated location, which is `/_nuxt/img` in this case.

If this is not your desire feature, simply put your images under `static/`, then you can reference them like this:

```html
<img src="/path/to/your_image.png" />
```

When the path does not contain `@` or `~`, the path and the data itself won't be touched by Webpack.

Otherwise, you can configure Webpack using [`build.extend`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#extend) so that it won't rename files with hash. However, this approach is [not recommended](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1720).

Comment: In the project IMG folder is inside static folder, but if I  call SRC including asset prerenderig compile olso all the images adding the final hash, but if I call the images directly with SRC=/IMG/IMG.jpg (instead src=~/static/IMG/img.jpg) the prerender give the IMG folder with unmodified images name and olso in the page the call is without the _nuxt folder...very strange

Comment: Please check my edited answer :)